# Как сменить текст строки приглашения ввода пароля?

Tags: linux, debian, аутентификация

Кусок из PAM-политики для аутентификации:

```
auth    [success=ignore default=die]    pam_tally.so deny=0
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=2500 try_first_pass
...
```

При вызове `pam_authenticate()` в *pam_message* выводит сначала *"Пароль:"*, затем *"Password:"*.

1) Как можно сменить этот текст?

2) Что и как отвечает за локализацию этого текста?

3) Как установить число попыток ввода пароля (не путать с pam_tally)? Чтоб если 1 раз ввёл (*"Пароль: "*), `pam_authenticate()` вернула ошибку, а не повторно просила ввести пароль (*"Password: "*) и это засчитывалось как 2 неудачные попытки.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то это из-за политики аутентификации, вначале речь про pam_unix, потом про pam_krb5.